# mongoDB/mongoose: Is it possible to modify _id when projecting `.find` results?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I tried `"_id": "$field"`, but it doesn't work.

`"_id": 0` removes the _id field entirely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using mongoose

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
       //other fields
    },{
        minimize: false,
        toJSON: {  
            transform: function (doc, ret) {
                ret.newField= ret._id;
                delete ret._id;
            }
        }
    });
```

and query like model.find()

using aggregation

```
model.aggregate([
{
$match:{}
},
{
$project:{
 "newField":"$_id",
 "_id":0
}
}
])
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I was looking for something to add to the `.find` query, but this solution is pretty interesting. If I understand correctly your solution will only apply when the `toJSON` method is called?  So, after getting the results from a `.find` query, I need to take the results and apply `toJSON` to them?

Comment: no no , Just use modelname.find({//query here},{//projection here},{other //options}) mongoose will automatically do it for you